# Adding a values to Mutex in tokio is causing moving error

Tags: asynchronous, rust, mutex

In my code I'm creating

```
let shared_vec: Arc<Mutex<Vec<user::User>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
```

which is type `use tokio::sync::Mutex;`.

I'm trying to acquire lock and add values to the list inside of `tokio::spawn`, which should work async, but I'm getting an error

```
value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

`here` is at the end of `tokio::spawn(async move {...`

Could someone tell me workaround for this?
Here is my code

```rust
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader},
    net::TcpListener,
    sync::broadcast,
};

use serde_json::json;
use serde_json::Value;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;
mod user;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();
    let (tx, _rx) = broadcast::channel(10);


    let shared_vec: Arc<Mutex<Vec<user::User>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

    loop {
        let (mut socket, addr) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        
        let tx = tx.clone();
        let mut rx = tx.subscribe();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let (reader, mut writer) = socket.split();

            let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);
            let mut line = String::new();

            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    result = reader.read_line(&mut line) => {
                        if result.unwrap() == 0 {
                            break;
                        }
                        tx.send((line.clone(), addr)).unwrap();
                        line.clear();
                    }
                    result = rx.recv() => {
                        let (msg, other_addr) = result.unwrap();

                        let json_msg: Value = json!(msg);
                        
                        let mut vec = shared_vec.lock().await;

                        let mut indices_to_update = Vec::new();

                        for (index, usr) in vec.iter().enumerate() {
                            if usr.get_ip() != &addr {
                                indices_to_update.push(index);
                            }
                        }

                        for _index in indices_to_update {
                            let user = user::User::new(json_msg["username"].to_string(), addr);
                            vec.push(user);
                        }

                        if addr == other_addr {
                            writer.write_all(msg.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `clone` the `Arc` to be passed to the `async move block` using `Arc::clone(&shared_vec)` in the loop block. You can then pass the new clone to the `move block`.

Without the clone the shared referenced is passed to the other thread / block and is not allowed to be used anymore.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I tried this at the top of loop `let shared_vec_copy = Arc::clone(shared_vec);`. But compiler says: `expected &Arc<{unknown}>, found Arc<Mutex<Vec<User, Global>>>`

Comment: The error above is happing in `Arc::clone(shared_vec);` part. When I tried to move it to the variable, the part above is still causing the error

Comment: @MarcelKopera Like the compiler says, you need to reference`shared_vec`: `Arc::clone(& shared_vec)`

Comment: after using reference for clone Im getting back the same error (first one): `use of moved value: shared_vec
value moved here, in previous iteration of loop / move occurs because shared_vec has type Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<Vec<User>>>, which does not implement the Copy trait`

Comment: @MarcelKopera Then you're cloning it in the wrong place. You need to clone it in the outermost `loop` before moving the clone into the async closure.